# How to load an experiment in azureml?

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service

I have many experiment, like:

[image]

and now, i want load an experiment

```
#%% sumonando os pacotes e verificando azureml.core
import azureml.core
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import logging

print("AzureML SDK Version: ", azureml.core.VERSION)

#%% Conectando ao azure e crinado o exparimento

from azureml.core import Workspace, Experiment

ws = Workspace.from_config() 
print(Experiment.list(ws))
#%%
Experiment = Experiment.from_directory('teste2-Monitor-Runs') `
```

but

```
"error": {
    "message": "No cache found for current project, try providing resource group and workspace 
arguments"
}`
```

---

Content: [azureml.core.Experiment class - Azure Machine Learning Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.experiment(class)?view=azure-ml-py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is that way.

```
from azureml.core import Experiment, Workspace
Experiment = ws.experiments["teste2-Monitor-Runs"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Following AzureML's Experiment class documentation, they define an Experiment as a container of trials or runs. If you wish to access the *container* or the Experiment as a whole, you can use just access it by name (as long as you have the right workspace configured). See snippet below:

```py
from azureml.core import Experiment, Workspace
ws = Workspace.from_config()
my_exp = Experiment(ws, name="teste2-Monitor-Runs")
```

Comment: No, this creates a new experiment with the same name.